# Get value in data object Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a data object, and i want to get on of the value from it, when i try to print the data:

```
console.log(data);
```

i got an object like the image below :

[image: result]

the problem is i want to get the **order[billing_address][country_id]** which i think is an object, but i don't know how to fetch it. i've tried :

```
console.log(data.order); //didn't work
console.log(data.order[billing_address][country_id]);//didn't work
```

Comment: try `data["order[billing_address][country_id]"]` its a whole key

Answer (score 1):

The name of the property is: "order[billing_address][country_id]"

To access its value try:

```
console.log(data['order[billing_address][country_id]'); // Should work
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the values you are looking for have keys that are the whole string:

```
"order[billing_address][telephone]"
```

You can access these values like this:

```
data["order[billing_address][telephone]"] //"5"
```

You are currently trying this:

```
data.order[billing_address][country_id]
```

What you are trying doesn't work because there are no variables `billing_address` or `country_id` that are defined, and the object is not that deeply nested - just has the above mentioned long string for a key.